# How would you write incremental power of tens in mathematical terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, formal-power-series

I love mathematics but I have not done much beyond trigonometry.  I would like to know

- (1) how to write this sequence as a formula $10^1, 10^2, 10^3, \ldots$ — assuming that can be written as a formula
- (2) what category of mathematics teaches the complex looking (eg: Greek characters) so I can learn more complex mathematics myself

Thanks!

PS. To clarify what I'm looking for I'm working on a multiplication scenario where numbers are implemented with linked lists per digit position.  Implementing the above is easy for me.  But I would like to truly understand in common mathematical terms what I'm doing.  It looks something like this:

```
482 * 38 =

               /     16   * 10⁰
     ones (8) <|    64    * 10¹
               \   32     * 10²
               /     6    * 10¹
     tens (3) <|   24     * 10²
               \  12      * 10³
                 +
                 -------
                  18316
```

In a linked list scenario I don't need to increment the power per segment as above — it gets simplified to ones being shifted by power of zero, hundreds by power of one, etc (since the position of the addition in the linked list gets handed to the next linked list item from one loop that indexes the second multiplied number (eg: 38) which is used for the formula I've asked about).

Comment: What have you thought of?  The pattern to the given sequence looks rather simple to me

Comment: If Greek characters look complex to you, then maybe any symbols you're not familiar with will look complex to you. Every area of mathematics uses mathematical notation.

Comment: Incidentally, instead of reinventing the wheel, you might want to look into using an existing library such as [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) .

Comment: @MichaelHardy And the categories that teach mathematical notation are…?

Comment: @DanielSchepler I don't think that applies for my already written Rust library https://github.com/danielpclark/digits/tree/master

Comment: @6ftDan A quick Google search for "rust gmp" immediately returned a bindings library for using GMP in Rust.

Comment: @DanielSchepler That library states each method is “not thread-safe” which won't work for me.

Comment: @6ftDan : All of them. That's why your question seems somewhat broad.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I didn't see any Greek symbols in Algebra 1+2 or Trigonometry in High School.  They didn't go beyond simple variables such as x and y.  So your "All of them" answer seems a bit suspect to me.

Comment: @6ftDan : Greek letters are usually used in trigonometry. However, the use of Greek letters is not essential to anything in mathematics. They all use mathematical notation, and there will always be some notations with which you are not yet familiar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_n = 10^n, n \in \{1, 2, \ldots\}$

Comment: Does this solution take into account the individual digits in their positions?  Or is this only powers of 10s?  How would this represent the 4 in 400?